# 1 to Many Query: Help Filtering Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Problem: SQL Query that looks at the values in the "Many" relationship, and doesn't return values from the "1" relationship.

Tables Example: (this shows two different tables).

```
+---------------+----------------------------+-------+
| Unique Number | <-- Table 1 -- Table 2 --> | Roles |
+---------------+----------------------------+-------+
|             1 |                            | A     |
|             2 |                            | B     |
|             3 |                            | C     |
|             4 |                            | D     |
|             5 |                            |       |
|             6 |                            |       |
|             7 |                            |       |
|             8 |                            |       |
|             9 |                            |       |
|            10 |                            |       |
+---------------+----------------------------+-------+
```

When I run my query, I get multiple, unique numbers that show all of the roles associated to each number like so.

```
+---------------+-------+
| Unique Number | Roles |
+---------------+-------+
|             1 | C     |
|             1 | D     |
|             2 | A     |
|             2 | B     |
|             3 | A     |
|             3 | B     |
|             4 | C     |
|             4 | A     |
|             5 | B     |
|             5 | C     |
|             5 | D     |
|             6 | D     |
|             6 | A     |
+---------------+-------+
```

I would like to be able to run my query and be able to say, "When the role of A is present, don't even show me the unique numbers that have the role of A".

Maybe if SQL could look at the roles and say, WHEN role A comes up, grab unique number and remove it from column 1.

Based on what I would "like" to happen (I put that in quotations as this might not even be possible) the following is what I would expect my query to return.

```
+---------------+-------+
| Unique Number | Roles |
+---------------+-------+
|             1 | C     |
|             1 | D     |
|             5 | B     |
|             5 | C     |
|             5 | D     |
+---------------+-------+
```

**UPDATE:**

Query Example: I am querying 8 tables, but I condensed it to 4 for simplicity.

```
SELECT
c.UniqueNumber,
cp.pType,
p.pRole,
a.aRole

FROM c

JOIN cp ON cp.uniqueVal = c.uniqueVal
JOIN p  ON p.uniqueVal = cp.uniqueVal
LEFT OUTER JOIN a.uniqueVal = p.uniqueVal

WHERE
--I do some basic filtering to get to the relevant clients data but nothing more than that.

ORDER BY
c.uniqueNumber
```

**Table sizes:** these tables can have anywhere from 50,000 rows to 500,000+

Comment: Please include the query you're using.

Comment: Of course, i'll have to make it appropriate for the public as this is for a client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, and the trade-offs depend on factors such as the size of the tables involved and what indexes are available.  On general principles, my first instinct is to avoid a correlated subquery such as another, now-deleted answer proposed, but if the relationship table is small then it probably doesn't matter.

This version instead uses an *un*correlated subquery in the `where` clause, in conjunction with the `not in` operator:

```
select num, role
from one_to_many
where num not in (select otm2.num from one_to_many otm2 where otm2.role = 'A')
```

That form might be particularly effective if there are many rows in `one_to_many`, but only a small proportion have role `A`.  Of course you can add an `order by` clause if the order in which result rows are returned is important.

There are also alternatives involving joining inline views or CTEs, and some of those might have advantages under particular circumstances.

Comment: John, thank you for the answer. I have tried the NOT IN selector in my WHERE statement but it seems to remove the row of the query with that role, but the unique value still pops up with the other roles. Then that field is almost hidden. This all relates to trying to test information and the information I need is the unique numbers but I can't use all unique numbers if they have certain roles. Haha.

Comment: @BenDains, I don't know what you tried, but the query I presented yields exactly the results you said you wanted for the data you presented.  Here's [a fiddle the demonstrates it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b56e/1/0).

Comment: Thanks John, I'll give it a shot with the NOT IN clause again tomorrow to make sure I didn't mess something up along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Pretending the table name is `t` and the column names are `alpha` and `numb`:

```
SELECT t.numb, t.alpha 
FROM t 
LEFT JOIN t AS s ON t.numb = s.numb 
      AND s.alpha = 'A' 
WHERE s.numb IS NULL;
```

You can also do a subselect:

```
SELECT numb, alpha 
FROM t 
WHERE numb NOT IN (SELECT numb FROM t WHERE alpha = 'A');
```

Or one of the following if the subselect is materializing more than once (pick the one that is faster, ie, the one with the smaller subtable size):

```
SELECT t.numb, t.alpha 
FROM t 
JOIN (SELECT numb FROM t GROUP BY numb HAVING SUM(alpha = 'A') = 0) AS s USING (numb);

SELECT t.numb, t.alpha 
FROM t 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT numb FROM t GROUP BY numb HAVING SUM(alpha = 'A') > 0) AS s USING (numb) 
WHERE s.numb IS NULL;
```

But the first one is probably faster and better[1]. Any of these methods can be folded into a larger query with multiple additional tables being joined in.

[1] Straight joins tend to be easier to read and faster to execute than queries involving subselects and the common exceptions are exceptionally rare for self-referential joins as they require a large mismatch in the size of the tables. You might hit those exceptions though, if the number of rows that reference the 'A' alpha value is exceptionally small and it is indexed properly.

Comment: I neither agree nor disagree with the assertion that "the first one is probably faster and better", but your basis for making that assertion would be an appropriate addition to this answer.